# Why does the function always refer to one specific parameter?

Tags: c++, parameters

In the following code:

```
int sum(int a=40, int b=20)
{
   int result;

   result = a + b;

   return (result);
}

int main ()
{

    int a = 100;
    int b = 200;
    int result;


    result = sum(a, b);
    cout << "Total value is :" << result << endl;


    result = sum(a);
    cout << "Total value is :" << result << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This produces:

```
 Total value is : 300
 Total value is : 120
```

Why does the:

```
sum(a)
```

add the (int a) in the 2nd block to the (int b) in the 1st block?

Im confused why the (b) value in the 1st block is used in (sum(a)), but the (a) value in the 1st block is ignored.

Comment: Uhm... you should get a starting tutorial and some information on what default parameters are and how they work. I cannot grasp what your concern is, is it that the names of the arguments to the function and the names in `main` are the same? you can rename the function arguments to `x` and `y` and see if that avoids confusion?

Comment: "Why does the function always refer to one specific parameter?" What does that mean?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez - dribeas I'm using TutorialsPoint, an online guide for C++ and Im on the "Default values for parameters" section.

Comment: @OpenTheCSV The variable names used in `main()` are completely unrelated to the parameter names in `sum()` looks like this is the source of your confusion.

Comment: sum(a) means sum(a, 20), because the second param has the default value when you do not give one value.

Answer (score 1):

In function `sum` you are using [default arguments](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Default_argument&oldid=663512918). That's why when you call

```
result = sum(a); // where a = 100 and the second parameter is ommited
```

in the function `sum`, the first parameter is take the value of this caller's `a (= 100)`, and as the second parameter is absent from the caller's end, the default `b (= 20)` will be used as `b`. Hence the result is

```
100 + 20
= 120
```

As **David Rodríguez** suggested in the first comment, use different variables name (say `sum (int x, int y)`) for no ambiguity and better understanding.

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum(int a=40, int b=20) {
    ...
}
```

declares the parameters `a` to be `40` and `b` to be to `20`, if not specified. This is a compiler service, so `sum(a)` becomes `sum(a, 20)` (`b` not specified). Similar to this, `sum()` becomes `sum(40, 20)`. `a` and `b` in your method `sum` are [default parameters](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/77-default-parameters/).

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it shorter:

```
int sum(int a=40, int b=20)
{
   return a + b;
}

int main ()
{
    int a = 100;
    int b = 200;

    cout << "Total value is :" << sum(a, b) << endl;
    cout << "Total value is :" << sum(a) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the `sum(a,b)` both of the parameters have values => it does `a+b` => `100 + 200` which is `300`.

In the `sum(a)` the second parameter is not set, the function use the default value (ie: 20) => `a + 20` => `100 + 20` which is `120`

---

The `a` & `b` you define in your main are **not** the one of the `sum` function

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should read a bit about default parameters in C++. Where you are on it, I recommend you to research a bit about overloading, since they are somewhat related.

On the first call you do to the sum() function, you provide both parameter to the call, so the variables a and b ,that you declared, are used, hence you get 100+200=300. On the second call tho, you only provide one parameter, so the second one uses the default parameter value, i.e. a=100, b gets the default value (20), so you get 100+20=120.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a function like 
 returntype Function_name(data_type some_value), then this is called default parameters.

For eg: if you write a function like,
int calculate_area(int lenght=20, int width=25)

Then when you call this function from main, you can either pass values to length and width like this,

```
int main() {
  int a=50;
  int b=60;
  calculate_area(a,b);
}
```

Or you can call it like this...

```
int main() {
    calculate_area();
}
```

See the difference, we are not passing any parameter, still it is a valid call to the function, because in this case.... the default values mentioned by you for length and width will be considered, which in this case is 20 & 25.

And about variables 'a' & 'b' in your code, looks like you are getting confused between name of the variables. Main() and Sum() are two different functions.
'a' of sum has nothing to do with 'a' of main. You will understand this when you will read how the variables are stored in stack and all.

Comment: You can use markdown inside the editor for code, select the region and press Ctrl-K (or click on the {} button).